# Insert template element into slot element

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I've built a custom element with a few named slots, something like this:

```
<template>
    <header>
        <slot name="header"></slot>
    </header>
    <slot name="body"></slot>
    <footer>
        <slot name="footer"></slot>
    </footer>
</template>
```

And I use it like this:

```
<my-custom-element>
    <div slot="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div slot="body">
        <h2>Body content</h2>
        <p>Body content</p>
        <p>Body content</p>
    </div>
    <div slot="footer">
        <p>Copyright 2018</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</my-custom-element>
```

However, as you can see this results in my DOM looking like `header > div > content`, `footer > div > content` etc.

I figured I could use a `template` element instead of a `div` in order to get rid of the unnecessary (and sometimes style breaking) `div`, unfortunately this does not seem to work:

```
<my-custom-element>
    <template slot="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Description</p>
    </template>
    <template slot="body">
        <h2>Body content</h2>
        <p>Body content</p>
        <p>Body content</p>
    </template>
    <template slot="footer">
        <p>Copyright 2018</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
    </template>
</my-custom-element>
```

Is there a way to send multiple elements into a slot without wrapping them first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns out you can simply use the `slot` attribute on multiple elements instead;

```
<my-custom-element>
    <h1 slot="header">Title</h1>
    <p slot="header">Description</p>
    <h2 slot="body">Body content</h2>
    <p slot="body">Body content</p>
    <p slot="body">Body content</p>
    <p slot="footer">Copyright 2018</p>
    <ul slot="footer">
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
    </ul>
</my-custom-element>
```

This is pretty unreadable and cumbersome though. And it just doesn't feel like good code. Being able to use a `template[slot]` would be much better imo.

Comment: yeah, another way is to use a dumb containerless component as a wrapper. <dumb-component slot="header">Stuff here</dumb-component>

Comment: @RabahG oh, that's interesting, care to elaborate in a proper answer?

Comment: I'd actually prefer to create a containerless `<slot-content>` element solely for this purpose.

Comment: That's what I meant

Comment: Why didn't you use default slot ?

Comment: I suppose a default slot would help a little bit, but that still doesn't help with the non default slots.